# How to ask if someone is in a hospital

Tags: sentence-construction

The scenario is: I am going to hospital to see my friend who got injured in an accident. Suppose that I have entered in the hospital and now I want to ask someone who works in the hospital about my friend (whose name is Ali). How should I ask him or her about my friend?

The sentences come to my mind in situation are as follows:

- Is there any patient, called/named Ali?
- Could you please tell me if there is any patient of Ali's name.

Comment: "patient of Ali's name" is not grammatically correct.  I believe you're thinking of "patient of the name of Ali."

Answer (score 1):

Those are both fine. They make sense and can be understood. You should probably try to give a few more details, and remember it is a conversation with a receptionist. You will need to respond to his questions :

> Hello, can I help?
>
> Yes, is there any patient called Ali? I'm here to visit him
>
> Do you have his full name?
>
> Um, it's Ali Uckan.
>
> And do you know which ward he's on?
>
> I'm not sure. He broke his leg.
>
> Well let me check...Ah yes, Ali Uckan on the Jean Brodie ward, second floor. Visiting hours are from 2 to 4 weekdays. If you follow the signs to your right.
>
> Thank you

You see I've used your phrase but I've added my purpose (to visit), full details (last name) and I've coped with not being able to answer the question (what ward) by giving information that the receptionist might be able to use (the nature of the injury)

Remember the receptionist is being paid to help. They will be more tolerant of mistakes, and listening carefully to you, so don't worry too much.

Answer (score 0):

"Is there any patient **here** named Ali?"
"Do you have a patient named Ali?"

Comment: Grammatically, these would work. Practically speaking, though, you'd probably want to provide a first and last name, not the first name only.